# ocLazyLoad didnt load js file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oclazyload

when i used 'ocLazyLoad' in my code like below:

```
var userLoginRoute = {
    name: 'login',
    url: "/login",
    templateUrl: "app/modules/user/loginView.html",
    data: { pageTitle: 'login', bodyClass: 'login' },
    resolve: {
    deps: [
        '$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
            return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                name: 'App',
                insertBefore: '#ng_load_plugins_before', // load the above css files before '#ng_load_plugins_before'
                files: [

                    'app/modules/user/assets/login-rtl.min.css',
                    'app/modules/user/form-login.js'
                ]
            });
        }
    ]
}
};
```

both  of js and css file load successfully but scripts in js file not works.

thanks for helping.

Comment: mmm..it looks strange the name that you put for your loadede module... 'App' .. are you sure is correct .. you don't have to put the name of you application..but of your module .. hope help

Comment: i changed the name but not work yet

Comment: Can you post the code of your form- login.js?